# Using TFS 2013 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-2013

We have a policy to upgrade to TFS 2013 .

We currently use .NET 4.0 & Visual Studio 2010 .

My question is  Do we need to even change our code so that it runs on the latest .NET framework & Do we also need to update our Visual Studio to 2013 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use TFS 2013 with Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 you need the patch:

[*Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server Compatibility GDR*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082)

(Installed it here, for use with Visual Studio Online earlier this week. Just note it will not work with "local workspaces", just server ones.)

Answer (score 1):

TFS is code-agnostic; there are no requirements put on your code as a result of the TFS version you're using. So no, you don't need to change any code.

You can access TFS2013 from VS2010 with a patch installed (as linked by Richard in his answer).